# OpenVpn Service is connected but no ip change

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

First let me start with that yes it is run as an administrator here is the route print
The problem is that the open vpn client says it is connected and it shows it has an assigned IP but http://canihazip.com/s says my ip adress is still the same

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 20...00 ff c0 36 c0 97 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
 12...00 22 4d 6b 98 fa ......Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1         10.0.0.2    266
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.8.0.129         10.0.0.2     11
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0       10.8.0.129         10.0.0.2     11
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    266
         10.0.0.2  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    266
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    266
         10.8.0.1  255.255.255.255       10.8.0.129         10.0.0.2     11
   108.61.152.187  255.255.255.255         10.0.0.1         10.0.0.2     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0       10.8.0.129         10.0.0.2     11
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link    169.254.208.12    286
   169.254.208.12  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.208.12    286
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.208.12    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link          10.0.0.2    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link    169.254.208.12    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.2    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link    169.254.208.12    286
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 12    266 ::/0                     fe80::920d:cbff:fe52:2141
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
 12    266 2601:4:2f00:76c::/64     On-link
 12    266 2601:4:2f00:76c:196c:bd7d:37a0:d63/128
                                    On-link
 12    266 2601:4:2f00:76c:1dc8:817b:ce0:bc80/128
                                    On-link
 12    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 20    286 fe80::/64                On-link
 12    266 fe80::1dc8:817b:ce0:bc80/128
                                    On-link
 20    286 fe80::fd17:8df7:b26f:d00c/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 12    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 20    286 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  0 4294967295 2620:9b::/96             On-link
  0   9000 ::/0                     2620:9b::1900:1
===========================================================================
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

ovpn File

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote hideip-usa.kryptotel.net
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert 202552.crt
key 202552.key
ns-cert-type server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: **You need to enable the redirect-gateway option.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the "redirect-gateway" option to your OpenVPN config file.

```
dev tun
proto udp
remote hideip-usa.kryptotel.net
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
redirect-gateway
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert 202552.crt
key 202552.key
ns-cert-type server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: I added the config file I think you want to see

Comment: I do not see "redirect-gateway" enabled.  Add it as a new line to your config file and try again.

Comment: I added the redirect and it is still not showing a new ip

Comment: Stop, then restart your VPN.

Comment: I did multiple times I also restarted my computer

Comment: After retrying and restarting for a while I had figured out the problem my peer block was blocking something I added an exception for the VPN and now it works thank you guys